# I want to read the pdf files from assets or raw folder in android

Tags: android, pdf

when i m run it i m getting this error like "File or folder not found" and " file dosnt exit or can't be opened "..

This is the code sir..
i want the how to view pdf files from assets or in raw folder sir.. its very imp for my project try to slove my problem sir.. and tell me clearly i m new to android sir.. can any one send me code cloerly how to do it..

```
enter code here




Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource:///com.example.pratice/raw/em");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "NO Viewer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Few, if any, Android PDF viewer apps will honor the `android.resource` scheme, and there is no `Uri` scheme for assets.

If you want to serve up a PDF file, copy it from assets or a raw resource into internal storage, then [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to make it available to other apps. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) that does this.